# Current Status of Sproutcore/Ember/Blossom/Sencha and Mobile devices (or alt frameworks)

Tags: sencha-touch, ember.js, sproutcore

I've been looking over Sproutcore, Ember and Blossom and other competitive framework efforts (e.g. Sencha) to select for a HTML5 client side application project. The state, information, and documentation from these projects is a bit fragmented and in need of clarity, so I am presenting this to the community.

My project is to be a native-like HTML5 application with desktop level complexity in need of a complete application framework, that will work well on desktops and run with good speed on mobile devices with touch awareness. The widgets should be native-like (not web-like), but customizable so to be unique to the application.

Questions/framework Requirement:

1. **Native vs. Web style Applications.** Framework should make it easy to
   build native-like user experiences with the ability to make a custom
   native feel (not just wholly imitating mac/win/iOS). Some of the text
   surrounding Ember indicates it is really meant for web-style apps - which given no
   UI layer maybe goes without saying. Frameworks like Sencha, can it easily accommodate custom widgets?
2. **Mobile Appropreatness.** Framework should be appropreate for mobile devices and have facilities for touch input and
   gestures.Several notes I've seen in my research indicate that Sproutcore and
   Blossom aren't very appropreate for mobile, and that Ember is better
   geared towards mobile (size?). It isn't clear whether the
   touch/mobile libraries are very developed in Sproutcore/Blossom and if they will be supported it the
   current state going forward. (and blossom compile to native is not acceptable). On the otherhand, Frameworks like Sencha, do they have the facility to work well on desktop as well as mobile?
3. **Framework Completeness.** The framework should be a fairly complete application framework, with desktop-like OO expectations and management for automatically and efficiently syncing, managing, and serializing the data model with the server. Not sure if there is much difference between Ember and Sproutcore, how do other efforts like Sencha stack up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question covers a lot of ground.  I will pick some quotes and answer them directly.

> My project is to be a native-like HTML5 application with desktop level
>   complexity in need of a complete application framework

Ember.js specifically bills itself as a "web-style" framework, not a an RIA framework.  That said, you can build anything you want, but you would be trailblazing.

Sproutcore bills itself as an RIA framework.  You have complete control over the DOM, so if you can do it in the browser, you can do it in Sproutcore.

Ext-Js is also a good application framework for desktops (Sencha Touch is for Mobile).  If you like the way its examples look, then its a good choice.  You can of course customize the dom and write your own widgets.

Blossom is basically Sproutcore with a canvas based view layer.  It just went into beta, so you would definitely be trailblazing if you went with it.

So, you can basically use any of the frameworks you mentioned for the RIA part of your enterprise.  I would eliminate Ember.js simply because the framework itself purposes itself for web-style (e.g. twitter) as opposed to RIA (e.g. iCloud) apps, which is not what you want.

> The widgets should be native-like (not web-like), but customizable so
>   to be unique to the application.

All three of your remaining options can do this.  If you like Senchas widgets, its a good choice.  I don't know if they are native enough for you.  That said, with any of the remaining frameworks you can customize the DOM to your heart's content.

```
Mobile Appropreatness. Framework should be appropreate for mobile devices
```

This is a tough one.    Sencha Touch (which is separate but similar to Ext-Js) is very popular and gets the job done.  It is performant too; a non-trivial app ran fine on my original Droid (which surprised me).

Sproutcore is very heavy weight.  It has mobile support (i.e. for touch events) but you need to very careful about the dom you create, so as not to overwhelm the browser.  I wouldn't choose Sproutcore for mobile, although you could if you are very careful.

> and blossom compile to native is not acceptable

That does not seem reasonable to me.  To be clear, NONE of these frameworks run natively on mobile devices; they ALL run in the browser.  Blossom comes closes as the canvas API is mapped directly to the native API, giving you a truly native app.  The only way you could get closer would be to use objective-c/java for iOs and Android.

So basically, at this point your left with Sencha(Ext-Js) and Blossom.  Blossom is still in Beta, you would be trailblazing if you tried it.  Sencha is established, has great support (Blossom support is good on irc), and a large developer base.

So Sencha is the choice, unless you really want to be cutting edge, and take a little risk.

Comment: Thanks for a very good analysis. My comment on Blossom was this: I find blossom to be very interesting. But the blossom effort states that it isn't really meant for mobile, but will have a compile to native option (not sure what the compile route is). Howeverthis application must be URL launchable not distributed through a app store.

Answer (score 0):

Troy. Indeed, ember can run with another view layer framework such as jQuery Mobile which can provide a "app-like" look and feel.There is a github project: https://github.com/LuisSala/emberjs-jqm. In my view, if you need very cool animation you can use blossom.If you want to build a app, SC or ember should be OK. I'll choose ember because it 's loosely coupled.